# In bash, how to store top-level dirs in an array for post-processing?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to get a list of my top-level dirs in a subdir, so I can post process them, e.g., delete certain ones. I have

```bash
# List the top-level dirs and create an array with the resul
DIRS=`ls -1`
IFS=$'\n' read -ra TOP_DIRS <<< "$DIRS"

# Iterate the array
for D in "${TOP_DIRS[@]}"; do
    # For now, just echo the dirs
    echo $D
done
```

The `ls -1` command gives me this for example

```bash
00 PRM - AUTO GA
00 PRM - AUTO GA Prod
00 PRM - AUTO GA Prod@script
00 PRM - AUTO GA Prod@script@tmp
00 PRM - AUTO GA STG
00 PRM - AUTO GA STG@script
00 PRM - AUTO GA STG@script@tmp
```

However, the `for` loop only echoes the first value, that is

```bash
$ ./clean_workspace.sh 
00 PRM - AUTO GA
```

So obviously my `IFS` statement is wrong. What am I missing? TIA!

Comment: [Why not parse ls?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Make sure you quote `"$D"` everywhere you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for `ls`. Just use a wildcard in an array literal.

```
top_dirs=(*)
```

BTW, it's bad style to use uppercase names for your variables. These are conventionally reserved for environment variables.

Comment: probably want `top_dirs=( */ )` to restrict the contents to just directories.

Comment: His original `ls` doesn't restrict to directories. I assumed that he only runs this in a directory that only contains subdirectories, so it doesn't need to filter them. Or it will filter them later with `if [ -d ... ]`

Comment: @Barmar, thanks this will do for now. My `ls -1` (that's a number `1` not the letter `l`), lists only the top-lever dirs.

Comment: @ChrisF Only if nothing but directories are in the current directory. Nothing about the `ls` command itself filters out other types of directory entries.

Answer (score 1):

Just addressing the issue of why OP's current code only processes one directory ...

`read` is designed to read a single line of input so OP's current code only reads in and stores the first directory:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' read -ra TOP_DIRS <<< "$DIRS"
$ typeset -p TOP_DIRS
declare -a TOP_DIRS=([0]="00 PRM - AUTO GA")
```

`mapfile` is designed to process multiple lines of input, storing each *line* in a new array entry, eg:

```
$ mapfile -t TOP_DIRS <<< "$DIRS"
$ typeset -p TOP_DIRS
declare -a TOP_DIRS=([0]="00 PRM - AUTO GA" [1]="00 PRM - AUTO GA Prod" [2]="00 PRM - AUTO GA Prod@script" [3]="00 PRM - AUTO GA Prod@script@tmp" [4]="00 PRM - AUTO GA STG" [5]="00 PRM - AUTO GA STG@script" [6]="00 PRM - AUTO GA STG@script@tmp")
```

**NOTE:** this doesn't negate the comment/link about why you shouldn't try to parse `ls`